# .replace not working for value in serializeArray()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to iterate through a form and replace any instance of a space with a + for a certain field. It seems that I can change the value directly, but I can't get it to replace any instances of a space within that value.

Please see my code below:

```
$('#search-form').bind('submit', function(){

  var params = new Array();

  $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, field){

       if(field.name == 'submit' || field.name == 'reset') return;

       if(field.name == 'location' && field.value.indexOf(' ')>=0)
       {
            // this is where I am struggling
            this.value.replace(/ /g,"+");
            alert(this.value);
       }                    

       params.push(field.name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(field.value));

  });

  do_search(params.join('&'));

  return false;
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

*Edit Thanks for the help guys. I learned something new about .replace today.

Comment: why are you using `this` rather than `field`? you used `field` everywhere else? why not there too?

Comment: Also, `replace()` returns a new string, it doesn't modify the existing string: `this.value = this.value.replace(...);`

Comment: It was a part of my experimentation. Both worked when actually changing the value and not replacing characters inside of it. In doing some research across stackoverflow it seemed to make sense. I'm still learning a lot, though, so I apologize if it's considered sloppy work.

Comment: Thank you, assigning the replace worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to assign the replacement to the value

so instead of

```
this.value.replace(/ /g,"+");
```

change it to

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g,"+");
```

so the whole thing might look like this

```
$('#search-form').bind('submit', function(){

  var params = new Array();

  $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, field){

       if(field.name == 'submit' || field.name == 'reset') return;

       if(field.name == 'location' && field.value.indexOf(' ')>=0)
       {
            // this is where I am struggling
            field.value = field.value.replace(/ /g,"+");
       }                    

       params.push(field.name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(field.value));

  });

  do_search(params.join('&'));

  return false;
});
```